# What was the real threat in The Ruins?

Tags: the-ruins

In *[The Ruins](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0963794/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)*, a 2008 horror film produced by Ben Stiller and based upon a book of the same name, six young adult tourists enter the eponymous ruins and discover that there's something else there.

> Namely, the vines turn out to be carnivorous, able to infest humans, and can reproduce sounds to lure the humans closer. Through a combination of bad luck, panic, and natives willing to kill to maintain quarantine, the vines only actually kill one of the group.

FWIW, I'm given to understand that the book has the same plot points as in the spoilered text above. While watching the movie, I noticed that there are parts of the film where parts of the background are moving out of sync with the rest of the scene and at a few points, there are slight ripples in the view. That leads to my theory below.

> Is it possible that the vines aren't actually killers and that all of the deaths are due to some sort of drug exuded by the plants causing the tourists to hallucinate or go psychotic (and/or the natives killing out of superstition)?

I'm looking for any evidence from the book or film that might support the latter point. I had heard about this film previously, and I could swear that this theory was advanced for either the film or the book as a way in which they differ, but Wikipedia and my experience of watching the film seem to disagree.

Comment: I haven't seen the film, but are you asking if there's anything in the book or script that would support your theory? Or just if it's possible at all? Because any answer to the latter would definitely be opinion-based.

Comment: I'm asking about the former. I'll clarify the question.

Comment: horror film ... produced by Ben Stiller...

Comment: On a side note, I'm not entirely happy with how the question is phrased, but that's the most non-spoilerific way I could think of.

Comment: can you be more specific what out of sync things you've seen in the film?  I've seen it a couple times but I didn't pick up on any of that.  Let me know and I'll try to go back and watch it again.

Comment: I just returned the video to the library, so I can't go frame-by-frame, but the one that jumped out at me first is a recurrent pattern of something like stacked white rocks in the background of several shots at the top of the tower. While focused on someone's face, the camera will move a bit and the rocks will move in sync with the camera (and thus, really, not move from our frame of reference) while the face and the rest of the temple doesn't move (and thus does pan with the camera).

Comment: The ripples are a bit less common, and are largely toward the end. I generally noticed them with faces, with the edges of the head distorting and getting slightly darker. Honestly, I'm starting to wonder if the thing with the backgrounds was bad CGI compositing, the result of something getting pasted into the scene afterwards that wasn't properly synced to camera movement, probably to cover up something they didn't want in the background like a road where they were filming. The distortions could be the blurring that people who are dehydrated get.

Comment: @Geoff
Oh, and this is the Unrated version if that makes a difference. I'll see if I can find a Youtube copy and paste a link to a relevant clip.

Comment: I just skimmed through the last couple chapters of the book, and it kinda looks like the vine is a scavenger, using sound mimicry and maybe air-borne (pollen or pheromone) hallucinogens to trap prey. Some prey die, and are consumed as food/fertilizer. Some infected prey  escapes (or would, if the locals allowed it) to spread the vines. But I'd have to sit down and read the whole book to make a real "Answer" out of it. BTW, the book is titled "The Ruins", by Scott Smith.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did a quick read-through of the Scott Smith novella "The Ruins", specifically looking for anything to support the idea of airborne hallucinogens, but I don't see any indication of it.

One of the girls has some auditory hallucinations even before they reach the ruins:

> ...Her head cleared a bit, and she found words for the rustling leaves.
>
>  *Take me with you,* one of the trees seemed to say. And then: *Do you know who I am?*
>
>  ...A tree on her left seemed to call her name.
>
>  *Stacy,* it whis­pered, so clearly that she ac­tu­ally turned her head, a goose-bump feel­ing run­ning up and down her back. Be­hind her
>  came an­other rustling voice: *Are you lost*?* And then she was
>  step­ping with the oth­ers into sun­light.

...but the increasingly irrational behavior of the student/tourists is just a combination of fear, heat and dehydration. There's clear evidence that the evil had outright killed others before them:

> It was the mouth of an­other shaft, drop­ping straight down;
>  the vines had been grow­ing across it, hid­ing it from sight. A trap,
>  she re­al­ized. They’d been lur­ing her and Jeff for­ward, hop­ing
>  they’d step into open air here, fall into the dark­ness. There was a
>  sharp whistling sound, like a whip might make, and one of the vines
>  lashed out, wrapped it­self around the alu­minum han­dle of Jeff’s
>  torch, yanked it from his grip. Amy watched it fall, its light
>  flut­ter­ing, al­most fail­ing, but still burn­ing even as it hit
>  bot­tom, thirty feet be­neath them. She had a glimpse of white—bones,
>  she thought—and what might’ve been a skull star­ing up at
>  her.

The evil is a bit more *aggressive* in the book than in the movie, but it relies on evironmental factors (heat and dehydration) along with a few auditory tricks rather than any kind of chemical influence.